# Azure Logic App toLower string function unknown

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

Is the documentation for string functions out of date because when I try to use toLower() it i get

```
"An unknown function with name 'toLower' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed"
```

I am trying to construct an OData filter to query Dynamics (CRM) - this is the code:

```
"queries": {"$filter": "concat('hat_',toLower('@{body('Get_record_(Preview)')?['hat_fundname']}')) eq true "}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
@concat('hat_', toLower(body('Get_record_(Preview)')?['hat_fundname']))
```

Comment: nope - I get an error when I try to save: Failed to save logic app xxxxxxx. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'List_records_2' at line '1' and column '128168' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'concat('hat_', toLower(body('Get_record_(Preview)')?['hat_fundname'])) eq true': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Identifier'.".'.

Comment: You have added '@' as first character before 'concat'?

Comment: yep. cant save that. I just changed it to be @{concat...} and now it is complaining that the value in toLower is not a string so I am on the right track.

Comment: If you modify your answer to include this, I will give you credit for the answer: "$filter": "@{concat('hat_', toLower(string(body('Get_record_(Preview)')?['hat_fundname'])))} eq true"

Comment: you dont need to modify your answer. you got me on the right track. I dont think the string() function was necessary.